# How to install tensorflow-gpu 1.12 with CUDA 10.0

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, open-source

I know `tensorflow-gpu==1.12` needs CUDA 9.0 or lesser but is there any possibility where I can install Tensorflow on `CUDA 10.0`? May be via source or using `Bazel`?

UPDATE: I tried downloading from Github and installing via Bazel but I get the following Error.

```
Python 3.7.1 (default, Oct 23 2018, 19:19:42) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/some-folder/tensorflow-1.12.0/tensorflow/python/platform/self_check.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import build_info
ImportError: cannot import name 'build_info' from 'tensorflow.python.platform' (unknown location)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/some-folder/tensorflow-1.12.0/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/some-folder/tensorflow-1.12.0/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/some-folder/tensorflow-1.12.0/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import self_check
  File "/some-folder/tensorflow-1.12.0/tensorflow/python/platform/self_check.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Could not import tensorflow. Do not import tensorflow "
ImportError: Could not import tensorflow. Do not import tensorflow from its source directory; change directory to outside the TensorFlow source tree, and relaunch your Python interpreter from there.
```

Comment: "Do not import tensorflow from its source directory; " sounds like pretty important advice

Comment: TensorFlow is not yet supported with Python 3.7, need to switch to Python 3.6, and then build from source for CUDA 10 support. See: https://medium.com/@vitali.usau/install-cuda-10-0-cudnn-7-3-and-build-tensorflow-gpu-from-source-on-ubuntu-18-04-3daf720b83fe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tensorflow doesn't support python 3.7 version. 
Requires Python 3.4, 3.5, or 3.6

see below
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Answer (score 0):

We need to just come out of the Source Directory and run the python file. If you are running a file with `python filename.py` command you need to shift the file outside the source directory.

When you use `import tensorflow` from the source directory it will import the folder `tensorflow` and not the actual tensorflow library